Symfony4 HttpClient acces denied when sending data to another server
I followed documentation of symfony to use httpClient to communicate between two servers but I'm facing an access denied problem:
Access Denied : {"parameter1":"test","parameter2":"test2"} [] {"token":{"username":"anon.","authenticated":true,"roles":[]}}
my code :
    public function buildHeader(): array
{
    return [
        "ftapplicationroles" => "ADMIN",
        "sec-fetch-user" => "?1",
        "connection" => "keep-alive",
        "accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language" => "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        "accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "host" => "serverUrl",
        "sm-universalid" => "TEST2024",
        "sm-authtype" => "form",
    ];
}

/**
 * @Route("/default/send", name="test_send")
 */
public function sendAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $data = ['parameter1'=> 'test', 'parameter2'=> 'test2'];
    $json = json_encode($data);
    $sendHeaders = $this->buildHeader();
    $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
    try {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'https:serverUrl/default/insert',
            array(
                'query' => ['token' => $token,],
                'body' => $json,
                'headers' => $sendHeaders,
                'timeout' => 30
            )
        );

        // Getting the content of the response
        $content = $response->getContent();
        var_dump($content);
    } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
    return new Response('data sent');
}


/**
 * @Route("/default/insert", name="insert_action")
 */
public function insertAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    // Handle data, perform any necessary operations
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $configuration->setComment('new line inserted..');
    $configuration->setParam('parameter1');
    $configuration->setParam2('parameter2');
    $this->entityManager->persist($configuration);
    $this->entityManager->flush($configuration);
    return new Response('data inserted successfully');
}

What I'm missing in my code?
Thanks in advance.
